# SQL: out-of-range value

Tags: sql, sql-server

The following query gives this error

```
The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
```

The field timedate looks like this 13/11/2012 uk format in the database.

anyone know how to solve this issue.

```
        SELECT
         PRODID, ITEMDES, QTY, StockCode,shipName, shipCompany, shipAddress1, shipAddress2, shipAddress3,shipPostCode,shipcity,shipCountry,shipCounty,customerMessage
         FROM orderedItems oi
        left join orders o on oi.order_id = o.order_id

            where( CONVERT(nvarchar(30),timedate,120) >= 
            <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" value="#LSDateFormat(form.fromDate, "yyyy-mm-dd")# 00:00:00">
            AND CONVERT(nvarchar(30),timedate,120) <= 
            <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" value="#LSDateFormat(FORM.toDate, "yyyy-mm-dd")# 23:59:59">
            )

            Group by PRODID,ITEMDES,QTY, StockCode,shipName, shipCompany, shipAddress1, shipAddress2, shipAddress3,shipPostCode,shipcity,shipCountry,shipCounty,customerMessage

            ORDER BY PRODID
```

Comment: _"anyone know how to solve this issue."_ store datetimes instead.

Comment: db was build before me and for some unknown reason its been stored as a varchar

Comment: You have a value on `timedate` that can't be converted to `DATETIME`, at least not in the format that you sepcified. Most likely something like `31/02/2012` or a velue with a different format: `05/15/2012`

Comment: anyway I canchange the type without messing everything up?

Comment: @Spike: That depends on how productive this table already is. But in general it's better to store dates in the first place instead of messing around with conversion.

Answer (score 1):

I think that sql-server might be interpreting your date as if it was in american format, that is `mm/dd/YYYY`, and obviously there is no 13th month, hence the out-of-range error.

You'll probably be better suited saving the date using the proper field type.